# How fast is .call() vs methods in prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to optimize the speed of my JavaScript code, and one of the things I have wondered about is how the speed of .call() compares to the cost of looking up a method in an object's prototype.

For example, I have a class with some 40 methods and properties in the prototype. I assume that generally somewhere between 5 and 15 of these properties will be overwritten for a given object. Would it be faster to abstract out the methods of the class to another object and use

```
var class = function() {};
var sub = { method: function() { this.prop = "something"; };
var obj = new class();
sub.method.call(obj);
```

[Edit] or even

```
var class = function() {};
class.prototype.method = function() { this.prop = "something"; };
var obj = new class();
class.prototype.method.call(obj);
```

[/Edit]

or is the more intuitive way just as fast?

```
var class = function() {};
class.prototype.method = function() { this.prop = "something"; };
var obj = new class();
obj.method();
```

In my limited testing, there doesn't seem to be much of a difference. Apparently, jsPerf is down too...

Comment: Those represent a couple of fairly different behaviors which should be of roughly similar speed on modern JS engine. It's not clear why you think one is a more intuitive version of the other given their fundamental differences.

Comment: For me, it makes more intuitive sense to use prototypal methods because the objects are all inherited from the same place, and the methods work a lot with the properties of the object. Using .call() seems like an invasion of the object. Also, the prototypal method is shorter in code.

Comment: Why would you deviate from the most natural prototype/inheritance-based implementation until you have proven that you actually have a performance issue that it's worth investigating and improving.  Premature performance optimization is a pure waste of time because you will spend time working on many things that simply don't matter when your time would be better spent on other things.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thank you for that piece of advice.

Comment: Ah I think I misread which one was 'more intuitive'. @jfriend00 is right, that kind of attempted optimization is completely pointless, to start with. And it's very unlikely you'll end up in a situation where you're going to gain or lose significant performance trying to out-think the VM about method dispatch - that tends to be one of the most highly optimized paths.